# What's the advantage of two pointers linked list implementation of Queue versus one pointer circular list

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists, queues

Princeton Algorithms course shows the implementation of Queue using linked list and two pointers - `head` and `tail`. I've implemented the same functionality as a circular linked list using only one pointer `tail`. I'm wondering what's the advantage of two pointers versus one in a circular list. It takes more space as I understand so why did they choose this implementation?

Comment: None. Yours is better. They chose it because it's conventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a circular list, then you *must* have a pointer to `head` and `tail` to achieve $O(1)$ enqueue and dequeue. Furthermore, if it is not a circular list *and* not a doubly-linked list, then without a pointer to `head`, we can't enqueue!

Some picture might help a little too.

1. Single Linked List with only `tail` pointer:

   [image: single-tail]

   There's no way to get back to the head to enqueue! We would have to remedy this with a pointer to the `head`.
2. Doubly Linked List with only `tail` pointer:

   [image: double-tail]

   We can get back to the head, but at an $O(n)$ cost, we might as well just add another pointer to `head` for convenience.
3. Single Circular Linked List with only `tail` pointer:

   [image: circular]

   We can get back to the head in $O(1)$! This is a good shortcut. In [circular linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list) this node can sometimes implemented as a [Sentinel Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) which does not contain any information but works as a separator between the head and tail of the queue.

In terms of additional space, adding `tail` or `head` or both is almost negligible. The nodes will be taking up memory no matter what, it's just whether or not you use a variable to reference them. Using a circular linked list kind of acts like a `head` pointer if you think about it. `tail.next` would be a synonym for `head`, so it's not really saving space, nor is it really costing much space.

Comment: thanks, so the approach with a circular list is better, right?

Comment: *Better* is a very subjective term. Whichever you can better defend for reasons why you chose it would most likely be a better choice. They both have pros and cons. It's really up to you to decide which one is better for your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

One possible advantage is that it is a little easier to understand how the push and pop operations work with a doubly-linked list.  The use of a singly-linked circular list is not *that* much harder to understand, but it *is* a trick, and at this stage where it's the first time you're seeing anything of the sort, any extra complication can be extra confusing.

Comment: thanks, _work with a doubly-linked list_  - I didn't probably specify it correctly. It's not doubly-linked list, i.e. the nodes don't have two pointers (next and previous), it's that instead of a pointer to first node `head` only there's also a pointer to the last node `tail`. Or is that also called doubly-linked list?

Comment: @Maximus, ahh, that is different indeed... but a suitable modification of the comments in my answer still apply.